# Как считывать с консоли команды в которых и String, и Integer одновременно?

Tags: java, строки, arraylist

Сразу сделаю замечание о том,что НЕ подсказывайте готовое решение. Это учебная задача. и по теме лекции у меня вопросов нет. А Вот как считать данные не знаю и прошу лишь дать направление для изучения.

Сама задача такая:

> Существует ряд методов для класса `ArrayList`: `add(n)` - вставка в конец, `add(i, n)` — вставка по индексу, `remove(i)` - удаление по индексу, `set(i, n)` — изменение значения по индексу.
> На вход программе подаются строки, первая из которых `create N` - создает исходный список с числами от `1` до `N` включительно.
> Сигнатуры остальных команд:
>
> - `add 5` — вставляет 5 в конец списка.
> - `add 5 6` — вставляет 6 по индексу `5`.
> - `remove 7` — удаляет седьмой элемент списка.
> - `set 7 3` — заменяет значение седьмого элемента списка на `3`.
> - `printList` - сигнализирует о конце ввода данных и должна вывести на экран список, полученный после всех манипуляций.

Данные с консоли я считал и цикл завершил.
Далее сделал список  разбив по `nexLine()` (в каждой ячейке у меня хранится команда и данные). Теперь хотел считывать через `split()` каждый элемент списка и понимать команду и значение для изменения (команду сравнивать со строкой). И все реально, до тех пор пока я в каждой ячейке списка получаю два значения (команду и цифры), а вот когда у меня три значение (команда, цифра и цифра). Сталкиваюсь со сложностью.

Конечно я могу каждую ячейку списка проверять на длину массива (еще раз разбивать строку по пробелам). и проверять длину массива.
Но может быть есть какой-то метод или класс который лучше подходит, чем куча `if`-ов или `switch`? Возможно задача решается через `Pattern, Matcher` (регулярные выражения).
Сейчас пишу разбивая на массивы и далее буду команды считывать  через `if`. Задача сдана с использованием условных выражений.

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<String> l1 = new ArrayList();
        while (true) {
        String current = in.nextLine();
        if (current.equals("printList")) break;
        l1.add(current);//list список всех команд
    }
   String [] [] arrcom=new String[l1.size()] []; //массив из строк как бы двумерный
    for (int i = 0; i <l1.size() ; i++) {
            String[] k= l1.get(i).split( " "); //двумерый массив
            arrcom[i]=k; // разделяем строку по пробелам и засовываем в массив
    }
   //считали сreate  и создали массив данной длинны и пото этот массив будем изменять
      int n= Integer.parseInt(arrcom[0][1]);//длинна списка
      List<Integer> arr = new ArrayList(); // список для изменений
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            arr.add(i, i+1);
        }//заплнии список
    // бежим по всему массиву и смотрим что надо сделать
   for (int i = 1; i < arrcom.length; i++) {// бежим по командам

   if(arrcom[i][0].equals("remove"))   
   arr.remove(Integer.parseInt(arrcom[i] 
   [1]));//удаляет
   if((arrcom[i].length==2)&(arrcom[i][0].equals("add"))) 
   arr.add(Integer.parseInt(arrcom[i][1]));//добавляем
   if((arrcom[i].length==3)&(arrcom[i][0].equals("add")))
   arr.add((Integer.parseInt(arrcom[i][1])),Integer.parseInt(arrcom[i] 
   [2]));
   if((arrcom[i][0].equals("set")))
   arr.set((Integer.parseInt(arrcom[i][1])),Integer.parseInt(arrcom[i] 
   [2]));
         }

    for (int i = 0; i <arr.size() ; i++) {
        System.out.print(arr.get(i)+ " ");
    }
```

Comment: Укажите язык в метках с помощью [кнопки править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1143768/edit)

Answer (score 0):

Как по мне , то лучше попрактиковаться в ООП. Сделайте общий класс команды, который будет парсить построчно ваши команды и порожать свои классы-наследники в зависимости от получе6нной команды. А уже каждый класс-наследник будет контролировать свои аргументы (например, их количество) и выполнять их для вашего листа.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public abstract class Command {
    
    protected final String command;
    
    protected final Integer params[];
    
    private static Command of(String args) {
        try {
            final String[] split = args.split(" ");
            final String command = split[0].trim().toLowerCase();
            final Integer[] params = IntStream.range(1, split.length)
                    .map(i -> Integer.valueOf(split[i].trim()))
                    .boxed()
                    .toArray(Integer[]::new);
            
            switch(command){
                case "add": return new Add(command, params);
                default: throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not implemented yet for command " + command);
            }
            
        } catch (NullPointerException | ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException | NumberFormatException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not implemented yet for command " + args);
        }
    }
    
    public static List <Integer> execute (List <Integer> list, String ... commandLines) {
        for (String commandLine : commandLines) of(commandLine).execute(list);
        return list;
    }    
    
    protected Command(String command, Integer [] params) {
        this.command = command;
        this.params = params;        
    }
    
    protected abstract void execute(List <Integer> list);
    
}

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Add extends Command{

    protected Add(String command, Integer [] params) {
        super(command, params);
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void execute(List <Integer> list) {
        if (params.length==1) list.add(params[1]);
        else if (params.length==2) list.add(params[1], params[2]);
        else throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal arguments for command 'add' " + Arrays.toString(params));
    }
    
}
```

Теперь дописывайте имплементации для остальных нужных вам методов, а также класс, для пользовательского ввода, из которого после того, как юзер введет printList, все команды будут преобразованы в массив, а также будет вызван метод List result = Command.execute(list, commandLines); в которой нужно передать массив введнных пользователем команд и список, над которым будут выполнены все команды.

Comment: Спасибо, но темы Ооп еще не было. Конечно ге-то в глубине души появляется мысль что надо бы создать функцию. В нее будем передовать строку. и Эту строку же парсить и возвращать  нужное. (или создать дуе функции одна с двумя переменными а другая с тремя) . Но пока пробую создать двумерный массив где в столбцы буду записывать  комманду и цифры. А дальше ифом проверять длинну столбца. Возможен такой вариан? Сейчас пробую двумерный массив заполять. Сплитом разбивая команду и цифры.

Comment: @Александр по описанию сложно сказать. добавляйте в вопрос код с "попытками" и пишите об изменениях в комменты, будем смротреть. и еще... слово "функции" будут в функциональной парадигме, сейчас у вас методы. привыкайте к правильной терминологии, так прще вас понять и вам понятнее то, что будут объяснять

Comment: Спасибо. Буду внимательнее к терминологии. Мой код как и хотел разбил на двумерный массив. Если будут комментарии по поводу кода, буду рад. Так как обучаюсь удаленно да еще и на бесплатном курсе. (диалога с кем-то поопытнее не хватает).

Comment: @Александр комментарии скорее всего будут, только для этого добавляйте сам код))

Comment: Я сейчас попробую самостоятельно реализовать свою идею. и обязательно покажу.

Comment: Ну что же я задачу доделал и сдал, тепрь подскажите на до ли ее сюда выкладывать? Сдеал через двумерный массив и условные выражения.

Comment: @Александр вам решать, показывать код или нет. исходя из того, что вы показали, это только малая часть задачи. вы организовали пользовательский ввод, результат этого ввода попадает в коллекцию. после чего реализован вызов add с 2 аргументами, причем это выполняется всегда (что тоже не соответствует условию, ведь такой команды может и не быть, а может быть add  с 1 аргументом). реализаций для других команд нет. прогресс текущей реализации составляет не более 10 процентов от задачи